# Why can't I understand this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

My friend gave me this sentence and said there is nothing wrong with it. I can't for the love of me understand what it means. And can't help but to think there is a more eloquent way of phrasing it. Can anyone help?

> I just don't want to wonder what job I could've had, if I hadn't been focusing solely on the business during my job search.

Here's the context: the writer (my friend) has the option of taking an average job, and focusing on developing their entrepreneurial spirit through exploring business ventures. Or to take a great job but perhaps would get too consumed in it (time wise) to have any energy to explore the entrepreneurial side. My friend is trying to express a want to obtain a better job, even if the focus is on developing the business side. Otherwise he would wonder at a later piont if he could have gotten a better job. He is trying to explain this to a third party in an email that was read to me. And this sentence caused me great confusion and a heated debate ensued.

Comment: Are you asking what the sentence means or why you can't understand it? If the former, is it clearer if you remove the comma? If the latter, you're in the wrong place. If you are asking us to rewrite the sentence in a more elegant way, you're also in the wrong place, see our [help/on-topic].

Comment: The writer is expressing that they are reluctant to consider what might have happened if they'd done things differently; Specifically, what other work they might have ended up doing if they'd had a different or broader focus while looking for employment.

Comment: @user867- I don't think they're saying they are reluctant to consider.  They are saying that they don't want to get down the road and then look back with regret, wondering what might have happened if different decisions had been made.

Comment: I think the hadn't is really confusing the sentence. Either that or the whole sentence seems very negative. Seems like there's also multiple interpretations of what the writer means. Is there a better way to structure this? Are there any structural or grammatical problema with the sentence? I just find it difficult to understand.

Comment: The whole part where it goes "could've had, if I hadn't been" is confusing yes/no?

Comment: This is my understanding of the phrase: "I don't want to think about which job I could have got, if I hadn't been so concentrated on the business while job hunting"

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat tortuous phrasing, but the basic concept (reluctance to consider a "what if" scenario) is common enough.

Specifically, in this case, the hypothetical scenario centres on the possibility that I might *not* have been so preoccupied with [my current?] business when I was jobhunting.

It's contextually implicit that I think I'd have got a *different* (and probably *better*) job if I'd been more engaged with the job search (instead of worrying about the business). But there's really only one credible interpretation, which is clearer with a little restructuring...

> During my job search, I was only really thinking about the business.
>    Had I not done that, I might have got a different job to the one I have.
>    I don't want to think about what that different job might have been.

---

One could of course contrive a context where I'm speaking *during* the job search, and resolving *not* to pay so much attention to the business (so I'll be more focussed, actually *get* the better job, and not have to worry about what I might have missed). But like I say, that's a contrived context.

Comment: Really, you think that's contrived?  That's how I read it and it took me several readings to understand how it was even possible to get *reluctance* out of it.  I guess we'll never know for sure without context.  I think that for me, the choice of *wonder* instead of *think about* makes the difference.

Comment: Here's the context: the writer (my friend) has the option of taking an average job, and focusing on developing their entrepreneurial spirit through exploring business ventures. Or to take a great job but perhaps would get too consumed in it (time wise) to have any energy to explore the entrepreneurial side. My friend is trying to express a want to obtain a better job, even if the focus is on developing the business side. Otherwise he would wonder at a later piont if he could have gotten a better job.

Comment: @victor you should add this "context" to your post as it explains *why* you  are having doubts on the validity/semantic analysis of your friend's statement.

Comment: @victor: What Mari-Lou says is exactly right - it's *critical* context. Obviously there's something the speaker wishes to avoid, *at the time of speaking*. If it's still possible to avoid [whatever it is] by paying less attention to a *current, ongoing* job hunt, what I've set out as a "contrived" context would in fact be the most likely interpretation. (If a new job has already been found, that interpretation is no longer feasible.)